# How to include external .inc file in Magento 2 Custom Module

Tags: magento2, 3rd-party-library

I am trying to integrate magento 2 with an ERP system. I want to include one **.inc** file in my module.

Can anyone guide me, which is the best place to include this file and how to achieve it.

Comment: You probably wanna look at `\Magento\Framework\App\Utility::getPhtmlFiles` and `\Magento\Framework\App\Utility::accumulateThemeTemplateFiles` methods.